# General Differences between へ and に

Tags: particle-に, particle-へ

So this is a total re-write of my question.

Outside of uses that include travel, walking, riding, driving, going or returning or any other form of travelling and moving;

What cases would it be appropriate to use へ vs に or に vs へ?

Comment: I don't know how accurate this is, but a professor once described it to me by saying that へ indicates a general direction whereas に indicates a specific destination... can someone confirm or refute this?

Comment: To begin with, がっこうにいきます doesn’t mean “we are on our way to school.” It refers to a future event.

Comment: @mamster great info, how and why is that please?

Comment: @mamster and thanks for the edits, I don't have a hiragana keyboard, or onboard IME. I was stuck using google.

Comment: @Kurausukun well the reason why i am asking is, the learning software I am using will sometimes prefer HE vs NI or the otherway around and I am having a very hard time trying to figure out which is correct and when.

Comment: Also in general, my japanese tutor says HE is used in conjunction with a verb like ikimasu that it means yeah I'll go there...and she says NI is more definate, like it's a specific destination happening right now and not in the future course of _yeah I'll get there_.

Comment: Escoce, this may be helpful: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/when-is-v%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-the-continuation-of-action-and-when-is-it-the-continuation-of-state/3140#3140 . One way to say "we are on our way to school" in Japanese is がっこうに行っているところだ。Non-past form in Japanese is used for future events more often than Japanese learners tend to think. For an event happening right now, ている form is typically used, but motion verbs are special—see Derek's explanation at the link I gave.

Comment: This is all ancillary to your question, of course; I just thought you'd want to know!

Comment: This may also be hepful: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55239/problem-understanding-この素晴しい世界に祝福を/55243#55243

Comment: I think my question got stuck because my examples use travel and so many other questions also use travel. I really meant in the broader grammatical sense of using the articles. I tried to add some exmaples that don't involve travel, but as I mentioned, I am still a language learner so coming up with really good examples is hard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When going somewhere, is there any difference between e (へ) and ni (に)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/80/when-going-somewhere-is-there-any-difference-between-e-%e3%81%b8-and-ni-%e3%81%ab)

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is that へ can be combined with の like 学校への道 (a way to the school) while に can't.

Other than that, they don't have semantic difference. In contexts where it's accompanied with motion verbs like your examples, they don't specify which connotation it is as you assumed.

On the other hand, に has its inherent sense or feel, which makes us imagine that something attaches **on** the object. へ derives from a noun which means "side" and it focuses on direction rather than destination. So, if the verb in a sentence is left out, people tend to assume different verbs according to each particle. For example, 明日へ sounds like continuing to 向{む}かう while what I first associate with 明日に is 延{の}ばす. However, once the predicate is determined, that's another story.

Comment: There's a really interesting corpus-based paper about this in *Usage-based Approaches to Japanese Grammar*  called *Interchangeability of so-called interchangeable particles: Corpus analysis of spatial markers, Ni and E* (Kaori Kabata 2014), which covers a survey of native speaker judgments, as well as corpus results from both speech and writing.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently read a web manga called `テストに出ない日本語の勉強` and it has an episode on this topic:

http://www.comico.jp/challenge/detail.nhn?titleNo=413&articleNo=3

According to it, `へ` is used in cases where the direction or goal is vague or undetermined, and `に` when it is known where and why one is going, so it seems to confirm your guess.

Comment: It would be nice if downvoters explained what's wrong with my answer...

Comment: I'll explain instead of the downvoter. First, OP's guess is not correct, and even though the indefinite claim in the link is true, it doesn't lead to OP's interpretation. It would be "に feels conscious of what to do there" or so. However, it just feels that way and not necessarily so after all.