# Why there is a "を" in この素晴らしい世界に祝福を and not a "が"?

Tags: particles, particle-が, particle-を

この素晴らしい世界に祝福を! is translated to English as "A blessing to this wonderful world!" . Why is there a "を" and not a "が" in this sentence? In Spanish (and I assume also in English) "a blessing" would be the subject, does this mean "が" and "を" dont directly correlate to the functions of subject and direct object, or is in this sentence assumed that "A blessing to this wonderful world!" is part of a larger unsaid sentence where this part is the direct object, is the sentence misstranslated to English or is there any other reason?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55244/9831

Comment: Related: [Does the particle “を” (wo) have a special use when at the end of a sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1209/5010)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an understood verb at the end:

この素晴らしい世界に祝福を（any verb of well-wishing like 祈る、望む、など）!

In English, this translates roughly to "(I wish) a blessing to this wonderful world!"

Comment: I see, it makes sense like that